# Silverlight and Windows 8 Consumer Preview working?

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-8

The Windows 8 Consumer Preview is now available. It is known that Silverlight will not run in metrostylemode, but with legacy/desktopmode it is working?

Anything unusual to keep in mind?

Are you able to access Silverlight applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there was anything new posted to that effect (but then the story was already explained in Dev Preview). It basically works the way you describe in Beta.

Comment: Microsoft keeps the important news til the last day. e.g. Silverlight will not work with ARM CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

(sorry for my bad english)

I have an medium sized SL5 LOB RIA Services app that runs OOB and it is working fine on windows 8 CP. The only thing that did not worked as I expected is that the on-screen keyboard do not show when I enter a text field. probably there is a way to p/invoke this but it would be nice if this happens by default.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can add a meta tag which causes the metro browser to prompt the user, but I have not yet tested.

Check out the following link:-

http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/33701-plug-in-free-web-in-ie10-metro/